# How to create an ad-hoc wireless network in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager

This should be very easy but I am finding it quite hard in Ubuntu.

I want to create a network so that I can connect other devices to my computer wirelessly.  I do not need an internet connection, I just need an ad-hoc network from my Ubuntu computer which is running Gnome.

[These directions](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/net-wireless-adhoc.html.en) are inaccurate, there is no "Use as a..." in step 4.

[These directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html.en) imply that I can not change the automatically generated password for the Wi-Fi network.  Also, see below, the network disappears after a few minutes.

The closest I have found is clicking the "hamburger nav" in settings and clicking "Turn On Wi-Fi hotspot" (pictured):

[image]

This does create an ad-hoc network but:

- The name of the nework is fixed (can't change it)
- The password is fixed (can't change it)
- After about 20 seconds the hotspot menu (pictured below) goes away and I can't connect any devices to it even when it does appear.

[image]

Why is this so ghetto? I could do this on mac in about 10 seconds. 
How can I rename the ad-hoc network and how do I make it persist (i.e. not go anywhere)?

The output of `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*` is as follows:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  dnsmasq        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  dnsmasq-base   <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*`.

Comment: @heynnema I updated my question with the output of that command.

Comment: Is this a hot spot or ad hoc network?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack unsure what the difference is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install `dnsmasq-base`. This should take care of your problem.

`sudo apt-get update` # update the software database

`sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base` # install dnsmasq-base

Comment: That fixed it. I still can't set the password or network name (bummer) but now it stays open and I can connect.  I have no idea why you knew that would fix it but thank you.

Comment: @Startec you're very welcome!

Comment: I have this package installed, but when I create a Hotspot it does not go visible in any Android device I've tested... Any tip?

Comment: @LEo  Does it work with non-Android devices? Did you try the next answer?

Comment: @heynnema does this solution work for ad hoc or hot spot?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Try it. It's a quick install, and a quick uninstall if it doesn't solve your problem. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting an Android tablet with bvnc, Ad-hoc is not the way to go.  Instead, Right Click on the networkicon, and in the drop-down menu, select Edit connections/ under WI-FI tab, mode dropdown, select Infrastructure (instead of Ad-hoc), then under IPV4 settings, connection method, set it to shared with other computers. Then the Android tablet could see the network, and connect wirelessly.

Comment: where are these options.  I don't see "Edit connections" anywhere under WI-FI tab, not any option for Ad-hoc (see above picture).

Comment: what does "shared with other computers" mean? What kinda network is that?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for help on how to create an ad hoc wireless network tonight. I found the responses above a little complicated. But there were some good points made like
the inability to change the password and the network name graphical menu. I also noticed that the security is WPA and not WPA2.

But the instructions on the link below are accurate. I rapidly setup an ad hoc wifi hotspot on Ubuntu 18.04 which I connected to from a machine running Ubuntu 22.04 :

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html.en

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1232506)